# Put files from PC onto a Samsung Galaxy S7 via Wifi?

Tags: samsung, file-transfer

I want to put files (images or pdfs) onto my phone as fast as possible using wifi (LAN over wifi). I don't care if it doesn't allow the files on the phone to be uploaded to the PC, I just want to put files onto the device from the PC.

- PC is Windows 10 distro.
- I don't want cables, over Wifi is wanted.
- I don't want to use the Wifi as an internet connection, I want all data to be sent along the local network (fastest).
- I don't want to pay if possible.

Is there anything I can do to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just install an ftp server app like [Primitive ftpd](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.primftpd) or other and access your droid using an ftp client on you computer, such as [Filezilla](https://filezilla-project.org). You can also do it the other way around : share a specific folder on your computer like you would for sharing on your home network, copy there the files you want to put on your android, and then access it from your phone using one of the various file explorer apps that allow you to, such as [Ghost Commander](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ghostsq.commander), [Solid Explorer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=pl.solidexplorer2) or [ES Explorer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.estrongs.android.pop).

If I remember correctly, you can also use [Airdroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sand.airdroid) to do that. It's an app that allows you to access your android device from any web browser, you can manage your contacts, send sms, etc., and copy files directly if you're on the same network, otherwise it goes through their servers.

Answer (score 1):

SSHDroid + WinSCP. I think it doesn't even require root if not using port 22 (you don't have to). Also allows resume transfer. Been using the combination on my own tablet whose USB MTP connection is not working.

Don't expect transmission speed to be high, though - 2MB/s at best and ~200KB/s at worst, far slower than USB.

Answer (score 1):

There is an app, called [FTP Server](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=lutey.FTPServer) which does this job perfectly. You download the app, configure it and the server is ready in under 2 minutes.
After you're done you can use the Windows Explorer to access your newly created FTP server. Just click on the address bar and type in `ftp://[IP-ADDRESS]:[PORT]` and windows will ask you for a  username and a password. That's it. You can transfer files to your phone with nothing more than a local network connection.

Comment: I already use WAMP for a webserver on this PC, any chance something like that can be used?

Comment: You mean you want to use a permanent server for your phone? That can be done with the app too. You just have to check the checkbox which says that the service starts at every boot.

Answer (score 0):

You can use apps that are designed for that purpose e.g. [AirDroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sand.airdroid). It's indeed free to use if you don't want some extra premium features. You can get that from google play.

Answer (score -1):

DROPBOX, BOX, GDRIVE, etc etc

You don't need a server. Upload to a drive, download to your computer or anywhere else. Simple.

Comment: Those are all third party servers to use for this. I meant direct.

Comment: This answer doesn't fulfill the 3rd criteria though: "***I don't want to use the Wifi as an internet connection**, I want all data to be sent along the local network (fastest).*"